# Unable to configure WSO2 identity server for openID

Tags: wso2, openid, wso2-identity-server

The problem appears when configuring the server to work with a real host name and not with localhost.

I followed the links at http://wso2.org/forum/thread/19721 but this doesn't worked.

Scenario:

version 3.2.3

Download wso2is, extract, execute: everything works fine, openID provider is localhost

now I want to use "whatever.myDomain.com" as openID provider name

Download wso2is, extract, create the store with the new name by following http..://blog.facilelogin.com/2010/12/deploying-wso2-identity-server-over.html, configure carbon.xml and identity.xml mostly by following http..://wso2.org/project/solutions/identity/3.2.3/docs/production.html, and start it up

In this case a) the server starts up but there are some errors in the console "Error while loading identity configurations ...bad file descriptor...and so on". The web console is up, and login as admin works, bot when clicking on Infocard/openid it crashes (error ocurred while issuing information card)

How can I configure wso2is to work with my own name of openID provider instead of localhost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are experiencing is due to a random bug in the configuration parser logic which is fixed in the trunk. More information about this fix is available here [1].

Other than that modifying the parameters mentioned in those posts should work.

This bug fix will be included in the next release. But you can get the diff from the following link and apply the fix and compile the corresponding bundle by your self.

HTH.

Thilina

[1] - http://wso2.org/svn/browse/wso2?revision=121681&view=revision