# eclipse comands.jar 3.3.0 dependency not found

Tags: maven, build, wso2

I am trying to build the WSO2 Carbon from source and the artifact for org.apache.axis2:axis2.eclipse.codegen.plugin:bundle:1.6.1-wso2v5 fails to build because an eclipse dependency cannot be found: org.eclipse.core:commands:jar:3.3.0

I am trying to solve the issue related to the "bad file descriptor" issue in OpenID as related here [Unable to configure WSO2 identity server for openID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600392/unable-to-configure-wso2-identity-server-for-openid).  The solution recommends a code fix but I am unable to build from source.

Can someone point me to a Maven repo with a clean version of commands.jar 3.3.0?

Thanks!

Comment: There is a [3.3.0-I20070605-0010](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.eclipse.core%7Ccommands%7C3.3.0-I20070605-0010%7Cjar) version in `maven central`, if that helps

Comment: Thank you.  No luck on the build, but I suspect I'm lost in the SVN repo.  Things have changed with the 4.0.0 release.  I'll try again.