# Issuer details are not valid. Issuer details should be registered in advance

Tags: ssl, wso2, saml-2.0

I am trying to run a test of the SAML2 SSO using WSO2 Identity Server 4.0.0 M7 but am not successful.

I tried to use the 3.2.3 binary but ran into the bug about long hostnames and the identity.xml file (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600392/unable-to-configure-wso2-identity-server-for-openid).

These are the examples I'm using:
http://sureshatt.blogspot.com/2012/08/saml20-sso-with-wso2-identity-server.html
http://wso2.org/library/articles/2010/07/saml2-web-browser-based-sso-wso2-identity-server

I've stood up a new Tomcat7 server and configured it for HTTPS, which works cleanly in the browser.  The certs are signed by our trusted enterprise CA and both the private key and chain certs are installed.

Same for the WSO2-IS host which has a new wso2carbon.jks with the private key signed by the same CA.  I've exported the host cert from wso2carbon.jks and imported same into the client-truststore.jks.  The trusted CA-signed certs are also in client-truststore.jks (at this point just to be sure).  They are also in wso2carbon.jks (used to trust the CA reply).

I've changed the HostName and MgtHostName in carbon.xml to match the CN in the private key; the Carbon console comes up cleanly with no SSL issues and I can log in using the 'admin' user with no problem.  From there I've updated the SSO configuration using the above example links as guides.  That works with no errors.

When I go to each site (e.g., saml2.demo, avis.com, etc.) they redirect perfectly to IS to authenticate.  However when I log in I get the error in the log "Issuer details are not valid. Issuer details should be registered in advance".  And then I'm stuck.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Have you done the 5th step of the topic 2 Configuring the WSO2 Identity Server ? Please check the value you've registered as the Issuer is as same as the one that comes in the SAML Authentication Request message.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I've followed it to the letter... except using the proper names of the server since these are setup with SSL.  Tomcat machine is https://tomcat1:8443/

Comment: Both machines come up with no errors.  The certificates on both are signed by the same CA (e.g., "foo.bar"), so no warnings or errors there.
The IS machines starts cleanly and I can log in using both the embedded LDAP and also the ActiveDirectory (when I tried that).

I updated the TC machine config.xml as such,
 <url>https://wso2is.foo.bar:9443/samlsso</url>

I added http://tomcat7.foo.bar:8443/saml2.demo/consumer as both issuer and assertion consumer.  

The error message is so straight-forward I'm sure I must be missing something simple.

Comment: WSO2 IS machine: https://wso2is.foo.bar:9443/carbon
Tomcat machine: https://tomcat7.foo.bar:8443/saml2.demo